# Redirecting the new user to the Facebook login page if no session is available with Facebook JavaScript

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, response.redirect

I am developing a Facebook iframe application in JavaScript. The issue is if the user hit my Facebook application URL, I want to redirect the user to the Facebook login page if they are not logged in and after they enter their credentials they will be directed to my application, NOT their Facebook homepage. Here is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Psych-oh! Meter</title>
    </head>

    <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>

    <script>
       FB.init({appId:'178012645616471', xfbml: true, cookie: true, oauth: true, fbconnect: false});
       FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
           alert("response");
           FB.api('/me', function(resp) {
               alert('Your name  is sub: '+ resp.name);
               alert('Your email id is sub: '+ resp.email);
           });
       });

       FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
           if (response.authResponse) {
               // Logged in and connected user, someone you know
               FB.api('/me', function(resp) {
                    alert('Your name is1111... ' + resp.name);
                   alert('Your email is1111.... ' + resp.email);
               });
           }
           else {
               // No user session available, someone you don't know.

               top.location.href='https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?type=web_server&client_id='+178012645616471+'&redirect_uri=https://apps.facebook.com/palmchipprojecta/&display=page';
           }
       });
   </script>
   <body>
       <h1>Welcome</h1>
   </body>
```

So when I hit the URL while I am not logged into Facebook, I see the Facebook login page's blue header and the below page is saying **Page not Found** and when I log in on that page, it redirects to my home page of Facebook, not to my application's home index page.

Comment: The sample HTML is not valid. The JavaScript part is outside both the <head> and <body> tags.

Answer (score 0):

Would you be opposed to using the function [FB.login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) to prompt the user to sign in using a  popup?

**EDIT**

I spoke too soon. From the FB.login docs:

> FB.login opens a popup window, and therefore you should only call FB.login when bound to a user driven click. Most browsers block popups, unless they were initiated from a user event, such as a click on a button or a link.

Comment: its not opening in a pop up it is using the same canvas as the other pages of my fb app so this is not an issue , something is missing in  the redirect URL .....

Comment: This URL does not seem to work: https://apps.facebook.com/palmchipprojecta/ -- if your app is in sandbox mode, you could make sure that the users you are testing with are listed as developers or testers in the app's admin panel on the Facebook developers website.

Comment: yeah its in sandbox mode and i have defined my role as developer so its visible to me .. u want to access this application?